Why does an intermediate field $L$ lie between its maximal separable subfield $L_{0}$ and $L_{0}(v)$?
This question is from the hint of the exercise 7, p59 in Kaplansky's book 'Fields and Rings'.
Let $M = K(u, v)$ wherer $u$ and $v$ are algebraic over $K$ and $u$ is separable, then $M$ is a simple extension of $K$.
Assume $K(u)$ is the maximal separable subfield in $M$ and $L$ is an intermediate field between $M$ and $K$, then the maximal separable subfield of $L$ is $L_{0} = K(u) \cap L$.
But I don't know how to prove that $L \subset L_{0}(v)$. It is trivial that $K(u) \subset K(u)(v)$. Maybe we could prove it by some facts about inseparable elements in $L$.
Thank you in advance.

It shouldn't be too hard to prove that $(K(u)\cap L)(v) = K(u,v)\cap L(v)$, which should prove your claim immediately.

We could prove it by the fact that $M$ is separable over $L_{0}(v)$,
